# Há algo semelhante ao composer php para Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Em `Laravel` temos esse comando para criar toda as estruturas de arquivos:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

- Existe algo semelhante para `Angularjs`?
- Existe alguma ferramenta que automatize a criação?
- Como é montado a estrutura de arquivos no `Angularjs`?

Comment: Bom, como guia você pode seguir este aqui: [Angular 1 Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#naming). Não sei como você teria algo para criar automaticamente já você cria arquivos de acordo com a sua necessidade

Comment: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular#readme

Answer (score 0):

Exatamente igual ao Composer até onde sei não há. Mas se você deseja ter um projeto base do AngularJS é possível usar o "angularjs-seed" instalando através do NPM.

```
npm install angularjs-seed
```

Ou você pode clonar direto do repositório do GitHub.
https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Como a estrutura de pastas depende das necessidades da aplicação e dos gostos do desenvolvedor, uma ideia para gerar uma estrutura padrão personalizada (uma espécie de template como no Composer) seria criar um repositório no GitHub e publicar sua estrutura lá.